# N-body simulation - forces for body not calculating in some instances

Tags: java

I am making a n-body simulation. For some reason, when I have two bodies orbiting each other and I add a third body, the two initial bodies stop orbiting each other.

EXAMPLE:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIGYY.png - earth is orbiting the sun, when I add mars, https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcrDK.png , earth AND mars does not orbit the sun and both travel in a straight line. Almost as the forces are not being computed at all on the body. How can this be?

Here is the relevant code:

UPDATE

```
public void update(float deltaTime){
                for(int i=0; i<bodies.size();i++){
                        resetForces();

                        bodies.get(i).update((float)(deltaTime / Math.pow(10,9))*timeScale);
                        lastTime = System.nanoTime();


                        //sets the forces for all bodies
                        for(int n=0; n<bodies.size();n++){
                                if(bodies.get(i)!=bodies.get(n)){

                                        if(bodies.get(i) == null || bodies.get(n)==null){
                                                System.out.println("nullPointerException error averted");
                                        }else{
                                                bodies.get(i).setForce(Physics.getFx(bodies.get(i), bodies.get(n)), Physics.getFy(bodies.get(i), bodies.get(n)));      
                                        }

                                        if(Physics.getDistanceBetween(bodies.get(i), bodies.get(n)) < (bodies.get(i).radius + bodies.get(n).radius)*distanceScale){
                                                collision(bodies.get(i),bodies.get(n));
                                                if(bodies.size()==i){
                                                        return;
                                                }

                                        }

                                }
                        }
                }

        }
```

The planets

```
public void sun(){
        sun = new Body("Sun", Physics.massSun, 20, 0,0, new Color(0xffff00), (float)0, (float)0);
        bodies.add(sun);
}

public void earth(){
        earth = new Body("earth", Physics.massEarth, 10, Physics.astUnit/distanceScale,0, new Color(0x0000ff), (float)0, (float)0);
        bodies.add(earth);
        earth.setVelocity(0,(float)Physics.getInitVy((long)Physics.getDistanceBetween(earth, sun), sun));
}

public void mars(){
         mars = new Body("Mars", Physics.massMars, 10, (long)(1.5*Physics.astUnit/distanceScale) ,0, new Color(0x00ff00), (float)0, (float)0);
         mars.setVelocity(0,(float)Physics.getInitVy((long)Physics.getDistanceBetween(mars, sun), sun));
        bodies.add(mars);
}
```

This is probably all the code that is relevant, please ask me if you need to look at the whole program or have any other questions. I could really use your help, the project is due soon. Please keep in mind that I am only in high-school, and I am not at all an experienced programmer.

Answer (score 2):

There was a different question yesterday about very similar code: [n-body simulation - IndexOutOfBoundsException occurring randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016211/n-body-simulation-indexoutofboundsexception-occurring-randomly).  You will want to read the answers, as yours looks to be susceptible to the same problem reported there.

Your particular problem, however, appears to be the placement of your invocation of `resetForces()`.  Since that method takes no argument, it must reset the forces for all bodies in the simulation.  You should therefore invoke it exactly once per time step.  Instead, you invoke it once per body, so each time you consider a new body you erase all the forces computed for all other bodies, too.

It seems strange, moreover, that you are intermingling position updates with force calculations.  I would expect the simulation to proceed in two main, *separate* steps for each time interval:

1. calculate the net force acting on each body in the simulation at the beginning of the interval, then
2. update the velocity and position of each body based on its initial position and velocity and the net force acting on it.

If you do collision detection (as indeed you do) it should probably performed for each time interval after *all* the position updates have been performed, not interleaved with the position updates, else in some cases you will compare positions from different times.

Comment: Although inefficient, the resetForces method is not the problem since the acceleration is also set when the force is set. Thus, even if the force is reset on a body, it will remember the acceleration and move according to it. But i've changed it so that it only resets the force of the index in the loop. 

Wouldn't the code be much longer though? Is there any reason to not do as I have done?

Comment: Could there be any other problem? @John Bollinger

Comment: Sure there could be another problem.  You haven't presented all your code, so how do I know what's in it?  And no, that is not an invitation.  This is not a code review site.